# Draw trend lines on a scatterplot with datetime variable

Tags: r

I have a data frame of almost 1600 observations with this structure:

```
head(df)

Start_Time Duration
1 2014-09-18 10:01:00   4 mins
2 2014-09-18 08:01:00  41 mins
3 2014-09-18 08:01:00  22 mins
4 2014-09-18 08:01:00  41 mins
5 2014-09-18 08:01:00  60 mins
6 2014-09-18 07:02:00  17 mins
```

I have plotted my data with this function:

```
plot(df$Start_Time,as.numeric(df$Duration), ylab = "Duration", xlab = "Date", ylim = c(0,450))
```

Since the data frame contains several tens of observations per day, I would like to draw a trend line in order to make it easier to read the data visually.

I tried this code:

```
fit <- glm(df$Start_Time~df$Duration)
co <- coef(fit)
abline(fit, col="red", lwd=2)
```

but I get this error:

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = df$Start_Time ~ df$Duration,  : 
invalid type (list) for variable 'df$Start_Time'
```

I got the same error with this code:

```
abline(lm(df$Start_Time ~ df$Duration))
```

From reading the error messages, I suppose that those functions can't hande non-numeric values.
I tried this and got no error, but the line wasn't displayed on my graph:

```
fit <- glm(as.numeric(df$Start_Time)~df$Duration)
co <- coef(fit)
abline(fit, col="red", lwd=2)
```

What is the correct way of drawing trend lines / regression lines when one of the variables is in the datetime format?

NOTE: what follows is the result of str(df)

```
str(df)
'data.frame':   4121 obs. of  2 variables:
$ Start_Time: POSIXlt, format: "2014-09-18 10:01:00" "2014-09-18 08:01:00" "2014-09-18 08:01:00" "2014-09-18 08:01:00" ...
$ Duration  :Class 'difftime'  atomic [1:4121] 4 41 22 41 60 17 17 2 3 3 ...   .. ..- attr(*, "units")= chr "mins"
```

Comment: Try using `glm` like this: `glm(Start_time ~ Duration, data=df)`.  Also, can you please post the results of `str(df)`?

Comment: I still get this error: `Error in model.frame.default(formula = Start_Time ~ Duration, data = df,  : invalid type (list) for variable 'Start_Time'`

Comment: Please post the results of `str(df)` into your question.

Comment: Sure, I was just cleaning them up (the dataframe also has some other variables that aren't relevant here): `'data.frame': 4121 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ Start_Time: POSIXlt, format: "2014-09-18 10:01:00" "2014-09-18 08:01:00" "2014-09-18 08:01:00" "2014-09-18 08:01:00" ...
 $ Duration  :Class 'difftime'  atomic [1:4121] 4 41 22 41 60 17 17 2 3 3 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "units")= chr "mins"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code that reproduces data in the format you stated, then fits a linear model using `lm()` instead of `glm()` and plots the results, including a line of best fit.

```
set.seed(1)

times <- as.POSIXct("2014-09-18") + sort(runif(11, min=0, max=1000))
df <- data.frame(Start_time = times[-11])
df$Duration <- difftime(times[-11], times[-1])

model <- lm(Start_time ~ Duration, df)
plot(Start_time ~ Duration, df)
abline(model)
```

---

The structure of the data frame is the same as you report:

```
str(df)
'data.frame':   10 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ Start_time: POSIXct, format: "2014-09-18 00:01:01" "2014-09-18 00:03:21" "2014-09-18 00:03:25" ...
 $ Duration  :Class 'difftime'  atomic [1:10] -139.9 -4.29 -59.53 -106.62 -200.73 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "units")= chr "secs"
```

Comment: Thanks @Andrie, it worked with a simple conversion from POSIXlt (as in my dataframe) to POSIXct (as in yours). I noticed it looking at your code (which works as is).

Comment: `model <- lm(Duration ~ as.POSIXct(Start_Time), df)`

Comment: `plot(Duration ~ as.POSIXct(Start_Time), df)`

Comment: @roccobarbi Ah, sorry - I didn't notice the `lt`.  You're correct - it's important to use `POSIXct` since this gets stored as a single vector.  `POSIXlt` is a list and useful for extracting elements from the date.  In practise, just always use `ct` rather than `lt`.